# Find minimum number of integers >=2 that divide all array elements

Tags: java

I have to find minimum number of integers, (where each such integer>=2) that divide all array elements.
For example, if the array is `[2,4,6,8,10]` then the answer is 1 (because 2 divides all array elements).
Another example, if the array is `[2,3,4,9]` then the answer is 2 (because we need at least 2 different numbers, 2 and 3, that satisfy the conditions).

I decided to generate all sub-arrays of the given array, store in a 2D array, then sort all sub-arrays in descending order of their sizes. Then iterate through the 2D array, and as soon as a number that divides all elements of a sub-array is found, return the index of that sub-array+1.

So, for the first example above, the first sub-array to be checked would be the main array itself (after sorting), and a number (2) will be found that divides all its elements. So, the return value would be `index+1=0+1=1`. However, this does not always work. Language is Java.

Comment: Please post your code, including example inputs and explain how the output differs to what you expect.

Comment: To find prime factors of an Array check out: [how to find prime factors of array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-prime-factors-of-an-array/)

Answer (score 1):

For every number the prime factors are decisive: 12 = 2 * 2 * 3, so {2, 3} is needed knowledge.

Having such a list of sets, prime factors, you need to find a set of numbers that then make up all sets.

Such an algorithm you work out on paper, how you would do it. And then code your algorithm out.

For instance a set with only one factor 49: {7} would imply, that 7 *must* be a categorizing number.

For a minimum between ambiguous choices, say {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {5, 7} you have to think of something.

Good luck.